# How to Mock java.util.logging

Tags: jmockit

I am new to jMockit and run into trouble when trying to test classes which have a instance of java.util.logger injected.
I've tried a number of ideas how to do this,,

Can anyone show how to me how to do it

```
public class underTest {

@Inject
Logger logger;

@Inject Service service;

public void doSomeThing()
{
    logger.info("Invoking Service... ");
    service.serve();
};

}



public class TestClass
{
@Tested underTest tested;

@Test
public void howToTest()
{
    .
    ,
    .
    .
    tested.doSomeThing();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be several ways to test it. I HIGHLY recommend you to read JMockit's [Tutorial](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html).

In your case this should work:

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class TestFoo {

    @Injectable
    Logger logger;

    @Injectable
    Service service;

    @Tested
    private UnderTest underTest;

    @Test
    public void howToTest(){
        underTest.doSomeThing();
        new Verifications(){{
            service.serve();
            logger.info(anyString);
        }};
    }

}
```